# Django REST Swagger gives 400 Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-rest-swagger

I'm trying to run Django REST Swagger on (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) to make sure I understand how it works, before trying to integrate Django REST Swagger into my larger project.

What I've done:
I took the code from the sample Django project and tried integrating Django REST Swagger.

In `setting.py` I added `rest_framework_swagger` under `INSTALLED_APPS`. My stuff for static files is as follows:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'polls/static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/tengelbrecht/Documents/ENV/django-project'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In `urls.py`, I have:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Polls API')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', schema_view),
    url(r"^polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    url(r"^admin/", admin.site.urls)
]
```

When I run the project on localhost (using `python manage.py runserver`), The result is as in the attached screenshot. The relevant pieces are the localhost on the left screen, and the terminal on the far right.

[image]

Any help would be apreciated. Please comment if you need any more information. I feel that there is a simple fix for this, as in I missed one step of integrating Django REST Swagger into the project, but I currently can't figure it out after hours of Googling.

Comment: Django REST Swagger works with API's built using http://www.django-rest-framework.org/. As per my understanding, you are using plain Django.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right, I needed Django REST Framework, not plain Django. I now have things mostly working. @NageshDhope If you put it as an answer, I can accept it, since this was the solution to my problem.

Comment: Sure @CoffeeTableEspresso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django REST Swagger works with API's built using http://www.django-rest-framework.org/. As per my understanding, you are using plain Django. Once you covert your current API into DRF API. Swagger should list your API.